# PHPickerViewController doesn't respect order of image selection?

Tags: ios, swift

We are building our code with minimum target iOS 15.

We perform multiple image selection using the following way.

```
func chooseImage() {
    var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
    
    configuration.selectionLimit = 0
    
    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phpickerconfiguration/selection
    configuration.selection = .ordered
    
    configuration.filter = .images
    let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
    picker.delegate = self
    present(picker, animated: true)
}
```

However, we notice if we are selecting images in the following order

```
0.png
1.png
2.png
3.png
4.png
```

We are not getting the same image ordering in `PHPickerViewControllerDelegate`. We will get the order in random fashion. For instance.

```
3.png
2.png
4.png
0.png
1.png
```

This is the code of our `PHPickerViewControllerDelegate`. It makes no difference whether we are using `DispatchQueue` or not. Both still produce random ordering.

```
class NewNoteViewController: UIViewController {
    static let theDispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(
        label: "com.xxx.yyy.theDispatchQueue",
        qos: .userInitiated,
        target: nil
    )
}

extension NewNoteViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        guard !results.isEmpty else { return }
        
        print(">>>> start the for loop")
        
        for result in results {
            result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier) { [weak self] (url, error) in
                
                NewNoteViewController.theDispatchQueue.sync {
                    self?.process(url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func process(_ url: URL?) {
        precondition(!Thread.isMainThread)
        
        guard let url = url else { return }
        
        print(">>>> url \(url)")
        
        ...
    }
}
```

Do you have idea why random ordering is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Which is random? The list of values in `results` or the order that your `process` method is called for each URL?

Comment: Is in the `process` method. Because that is the only place I can print and look at what is the URL being processed.

Comment: The calls to `loadFileRepresentation` are async. There's no guarantee that each completion handler will be called in the same order that you iterate through the array. You need to take steps to put the final URLs in the same order as the `results` array.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng have the same issue...did you by chance find a workaround or solve?